# Python - Choose bins automatically such that resulting frequency distribution is normal

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

imagine the following extract from a generic dataframe:

```
       id          X
     -----------------
     "A11"       1115
     "B23"       2520
     "B55"        310
     "C77"        500
     "D67"       5759
     "E44"        999
     "E54"       3150
     "F43"       1850
     "A33"       4212
     "R54"       2740
       .           .
       .           .
       .           .
```

I now want to bin X in a way, such that the resulting frequency distribution is normally distributed. I just want to specify the number of bins there should be, but not the actual boundaries. As far as I am aware, pd.cut will only allow for manual bin inputs and I couldnt find anything like this within numpy or scipy.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does this imply that you are indifferent to which id gets which number of appearance in the distribution (X) ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just want to specify the number of bins.

Comment: have you tried [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) : `pd.qcut(df.X,no_of_bins)`